# Keep UITableViewCell in front of other cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to keep the lower cells in front of the cells above them. I have a subview in a cell that would ideally go behind the cell below. I am having trouble finding where to put the code to do this. I think I am supposed to use this snippet of code:

```
for i in 0 ..< arrayWarningTitles.count{
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
        self.tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell!)
}
```

but I am not sure where, as I have tried a few different places and none have worked (willDeselectRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath), and I would also like it on the initial load up as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE (Added Table View Code)**:

Here is the bulk of my Table View code, if it helps anyone, I have removed the above snippet as it is not working.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selection = indexPath.row
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    //  self.tableView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()


    return indexPath;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    // Configure the cell...

    let warningTitle = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    let expirationTime = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
    let textView = self.view.viewWithTag(5) as? UITextView
    let grayBackground = self.view.viewWithTag(6)
    let redBackground = self.view.viewWithTag(7)

    warningTitle?.text = arrayWarningTitles[indexPath.row]

    redBackground!.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    redBackground!.layer.cornerRadius  = 20;
    grayBackground!.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    grayBackground!.layer.cornerRadius  = 20;

    redBackground?.clipsToBounds = false;
    cell.clipsToBounds = false;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false;
    cell.contentView.superview?.clipsToBounds = false;
    self.tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{


    if (indexPath.row == selection) { //change 0 to whatever cell index you want taller
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 140 - 64;
    }
    return 58;//Choose your custom row height
}
```

Comment: Why are your cells overlapping? Can you say more about what you have and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a vertical card type view, with information displayed just above the cell below.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your full implementation, but my instinct is that you would put it in `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`. But this is a hack — `UITableView` doesn't really support layouts like that. A more robust solution would use `UICollectionView`

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it didn't work, how would you do something like this in a UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you would be far better served with a a custom layout for `UICollectionView`.

I would recommend looking at a project [such as this one](https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController) and modifying the code in whichever way would serve you best.